# passing variable from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to know why the variable user won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var user = <?php echo $r;?>;
     document.write(user);
</script>

<form method="post" action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br><br>
     <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="password"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" ="loadXMLDoc()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `$r` is a string, you need to wrap it in quotes:

```
var user = '<?php echo $r;?>';
```

Without the quotes, the browser is seeing:

```
var user = Sandeep;
```

Better still, use PHP to JSON encode the string, which will escape any quotes and prevent an XSS vulnerability:

```
var user = <?php echo json_encode($r);?>;
```

---

Side note, echoing `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` into HTML is known XSS vulnerability. You should run it through `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
<form method="post" action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>">
```

Comment: Doesn't `<?php echo json_encode($r);?>` also need to be wrapped in quotes?

Comment: No it adds the quotes if you try to json encode a string :)